# publish profile in VS 15 Enterprice

Tags: visual-studio

i have a website project in vs 15  enterprice and i want to host it by publish profile through vs 15 but i got this error. Why ? i'm following https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1286/how-do-i-deploy-visual-studio-2013-web-application-project-to-discountasp_net-server.aspx         [error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dy54.png)

Comment: have you entered correct credentials?

Comment: yes i entered ftp cardinals correct

Comment: it also show ftp method scroll down

Comment: are you able to sign in into FTP server using any ftp client?

Comment: sorry i didn't mean u elobrate please

Comment: i'm using myasp.net hosting and using that ftp details